# How to make eval to return zero instead of nothing?

Tags: perl

I am trying to evaluate a set of environment variables before proceeding with the code any further
Here is the piece:

```
for my $var qw(ENV_VAR1 ENV_VAR2 ENV_VAR3) {
    my $value = eval '$ENV{"$var"}';
    print "$var = $value\n";
    die "$var not defined, exiting .." unless $value;
}
```

It throws an error for the print line:

> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
>   ./mycode.pl line 205.

Does it mean that `eval` actually returns nothing? How to make it return zero or maybe the whole piece can be done in a better way?

Strangely enough, if I define and then undefine the variable in the underlying ksh (e.g.`export ENV_VAR1=anything;export ENV_VAR1=;`) then it duly dies with the correct message but then it gives me another `uninitialized value` for the next variable.

Comment: Instead of `my $value = eval '$ENV{"$var"}'`, Why don't you just write `my $value = $ENV{$var}`?

Comment: it doesn't expand $var

Comment: hmm.. you're right, it seemed like at some point code refused to expand $var.. so i used eval

Comment: `my $value = $ENV{$var} // 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't compile. It needs additional parentheses around `qw( ... )`

There is no need for `eval` here. You can just fetch the environment variable with `$ENV{$var}`, which will be `undef` if there is no such variable

It is very simple to test to an undefined value and behave accordingly, perhaps like this?

```
for my $var ( qw/ ENV_VAR1 ENV_VAR2 ENV_VAR3 / ) {

    my $value = $ENV{$var};

    die "\$value not defined, exiting .." unless defined $value;

    print "\$var = $value\n";
}
```

If you use `export ENV_VAR1=` then you are setting the variable to the *empty string*, and `$ENV{ENV_VAR1}` will be defined, but have a length of zero. To remove the environment variable, you need to `unset ENV_VAR1`, when `$ENV{ENV_VAR1}` will become *undefined*

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there's a simpler way:

```
if (defined $ENV{"VAR"}) {
    # true for "export VAR=;" and "export VAR=VAL;"
} else {
    # VAR is not set (not even to an empty value)
}
```

As of Perl 5.10 there is the [defined-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator `//`, which is quite handy in your case:

```
$value = $ENV{"VAR"} // "VAR is not defined";
$value = $ENV{"VAR"} || "VAR is not defined or set to an empty string or 0";
```

In your case:

```
my $value = $ENV{$var} // 0;
```

Comment: *"true for "export VAR=;" and "export VAR=VAL;""* Are you sure about that? So there's no way of telling whether an environment variable is empty or contains `1`, (or whatever *true* value you think it returns)

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I am sure. Did you notice the `defined` in my `if`? If so, then please show me an example where the code is wrong.

Comment: Ah okay. Regardless of the `defined`, I thought your comment referred to the value of `$ENV{...}`. `export VAR=` sets the variable to an empty string and exports it. To get an `undef` value you have to `unset VAR`, so strictly your *wasn't set* should be *isn't set*.

Comment: @Borodin I just noticed the OP wasn't asking for a replacement of "undef" with "0" but merely whether `$ENV{$var}` is or is not defined. So your answer is the better one anyway. And right now the `exists` operator pops into my mind...